# PCI-e Power - Does 6 + 2 Equal 8?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I'm building a PC for a friend using a [Gigabyte GV-N960WF2OC-4GD](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5401#ov) graphics card which requires one 6-pin & one 8-pin power connector.  Now I'm looking at a [Cooler Master B700 ver.2 700W](http://www.cclonline.com/product/169340/RS700-ACABB1-UK/Power-Supplies/Cooler-Master-B-Series-V2-700W-80-efficiency-Power-Supply-Unit-with-UK-Cable/PSU0769/) power supply which has two 6 + 2 connectors.  My gut (and maths) say that this PSU will be fine but since I'm not playing with my own money I'm hoping for someone to confirm this for me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Short answer:
Yes

Long answer:
Yes you can mix them anyway you prefer to.
Even if it has only 6 pins you can always buy a converter like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001TK3TJY)

For an in depth description You can read this article:
http://www.playtool.com/pages/psuconnectors/connectors.html

> Some video cards have 6 Pin PCI Express power connectors and others
>   have 8 Pin PCI Express power connectors. Many power supplies come with
>   a 6+2 PCI Express power cable which is compatible with both kinds of
>   video cards. The 6+2 PCI Express power cable is made up of two pieces:
>   a 6 pin piece, and a 2 pin piece. If you put the two pieces together
>   then you have a full 8 pin PCI Express power cable. But if you split
>   the connector into two parts then you can plug the 6 pin part into the
>   older 6 pin PCI Express connector and leave the 2 pin part unplugged.
>   That way, your power supply only needs to have one 6+2 cable to be
>   compatible with both 6 pin and 8 pin PCI Express connectors.

Comment: This is a good answer.  Keep submitting answers like this.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks.  The quote is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for.  Thanks for putting my mind at rest.